# A video lecture series which explains the modern linux memory management subsystem in detail with code walk through

Tags: resource-request, operating-systems, linux

Any detailed video lecture series which explains each component of the modern Linux memory management subsystem in great detail, with code walk-through, and good slides?

Comment: I'm also looking for it. Linux with operating system concepts is a good start.